# Django admin inline "add more item" button not working

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-admin

Trying to learn stacked inlines in Django. Have a very basic setup

For admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import Picture, Review


class ReviewInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Review
    save_on_top = True
    fields = ["reviewer"]

#@admin.register(Picture)
class PictureAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    save_on_top = True
    fields = ["painter"]
    inlines = [ReviewInline,]


admin.site.register(Review)
admin.site.register(Picture, PictureAdmin)
```

For models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Picture(models.Model):
    painter = models.CharField(("painter"), max_length=255)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.painter


class Review(models.Model):
    picture = models.ForeignKey(Picture, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    reviewer = models.CharField( max_length=255)
    extra = 0
    def __str__(self):
        return self.reviewer
```

[image: Here is a picture]

As can be seen there is no "add more item" button. I think this might be a JS issue but am not sure(I do have JS enabled in browser)

Anyone has any idea?

Comment: Is there a tutorial you're following to get this feature?

Comment: Sorta. This is pretty close  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Admin_site

Comment: What happens if you try the `admin.TabularInline`? Does that show the add more button?

Comment: Tabular and Stacked are just different views. The problem still remains

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearing my Google Chrome cache solved it! I got a clue after realizing that the example worked in Microsoft Edge.

Comment: That is very surprising!  haha

Answer (score 1):

I beleive you have the `extra=0` in the wrong class, it should be in the `Inline` not the `Model`...

Remove `extra=0` from the model

```
class Review(models.Model):
    picture = models.ForeignKey(Picture, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    reviewer = models.CharField( max_length=255)

    # extra = 0     <---- remove this

    def __str__(self):
        return self.reviewer
```

Add it to the Inline:

```
class ReviewInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Review
    save_on_top = True
    extra = 0
    fields = ["reviewer"]
```

---

Justification comes from this snippet from [this example](https://djangotricks.blogspot.com/2016/12/django-administration-inlines-for-inlines.html):

```
@admin.register(Painter)
class PainterAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    save_on_top = True
    fields = ["name"]
    inlines = [PictureInline]


class ReviewInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Review
    extra = 0
    fields = ["reviewer", "comment"]
```

---

**Edit:** Second thought you may also want to get rid of the `save_on_top` from the inline as well?

Comment: You are right about the extra. In making a working example I was being hasty. However that still does not solve the issue. Look for my answer below